# Kotlin when expression issue for calculating (calculator) new to kotlin

Tags: kotlin, operators, mismatch

//Error due to receive type mismatch but it the logic seems ok to me

```
fun main(args : Array<String>){


    println("Enter a number")
    var a = readLine()

    println("Choose your operator")
    val operator = readLine()

    println("Enter a second number")
    var b = readLine()

    var result = when (operator) {
         "+" -> a + b
         "-" -> a - b
         "*" -> a * b
         "/" -> a / b
         else -> "invalid operator or number"
     }
     println("Results = $result")
 }
```

Comment: Your IDE will be giving you all the info you need to identify the problem.  Hint: what types are `a` and `b`?  Can you use the `-`, `*`, and `/` operators on those types?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, `a` and `b` are type `String`. This means they don't have the `-`, `/`, or `*` operators. I'm going to guess you probably want them to be `Int`s so you can perform mathematical operations with them.

To do that, we can convert them to `Int` after we read them:

```
println("Enter a number")
var a: Int = readLine()?.toInt() ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Must be an Int")

println("Enter a second number")
var b: Int = readLine().toInt() ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Must be an Int")
```

I've explicitly typed `a` and `b` as `Int`s in this example, so we can see how it works. What this new code says is "read a line of input and try to turn it into an `Int`, if that doesn't work, throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. You could rewrite this to keep trying, but we're going to leave that bit up to you.

One more thing I would fix is that `result` is type `Any` because it can be either an `Int` (if we know about the operator) or a `String` (if we don't). I would change it so the invalid operator also throws an exception.

And again, I've typed this explicitly as `Int`:

```
var result: Int = when (operator) {
    "+" -> a + b
    "-" -> a - b
    "*" -> a * b
    "/" -> a / b
    else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid operator")
}
```

Comment: This is better, with throw expection

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException("Must be an Int")` will be thrown only if the _"standard" input stream is redirected to a file and the end of file has been reached_. This exception won't be thrown if `readLine()` returns `String`, which isn't `Int` in this case `toInt` will throw `NumberFormatException`. Consider replacing `readLine().toInt() ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Must be an Int")` with `requireNotNull(readLine()) { "The end of file has been reached" }.toInt()` and extracting it to a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have input value as string, you have to convert them to int.

Here my code:

```
fun main(){


    println("Enter a number")
    val a = readLine()?.toInt()

    println("Choose your operator")
    val operator = readLine()

    println("Enter a second number")
    val b = readLine()?.toInt()


    if( a != null && b != null) {
        val result = when (operator) {
            "+" -> a + b
            "-" -> a - b
            "*" -> a * b
            "/" -> a / b
            else -> "invalid operator or number"
        }
        println("Results = $result")
    }
}
```